# Using optional parameters with a stateful widget class in flutter

Tags: flutter, optional-parameters, statefulwidget

I am trying to create a stateful widget that accepts some required arguments and some optional ones. The optional ones will have a set default value if nothing has been passed. I have applied the same process as you would for achieving this in a general class or function but for some reason it does not like it when using it within the stateful widget. Why is this and is there a way to get this working?

Currently getting this from VS code linting:

> This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: Example.inActivedartmust_be_immutable

This is my code:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  Example({super.key, required this.name, required this.age, inActive = false});

  final String name;
  final int age;
  bool? inActive;

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Thank you appreciate your time and effort, with my query.

Comment: Widgets should be immutable. If their parameters change, then they should be rebuilt with the new parameters. If you need mutable state, then place it in your state class.

Answer (score 2):

Just make the *inActive* field *final*.

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
      Example({super.key, required this.name, required this.age, this.inActive = false});

      final String name;
      final int age;
      final bool inActive;
      ....
```